# Guidance on Jacobian computation for stiff chemical mechanisms

Tags: computational-chemistry

I'm writing an implicit solver that will involve evaluating the chemical source terms in the system for a given reaction mechanism. It's safe to assume that these mechanisms may be stiff. I know, in general, how to approach the problem but I am looking for some very specific guidance.

The scheme requires the computation of the source-term Jacobian. The mechanism takes in the state variables (pressure, temperature, density) and the species mass fractions then returns the change in partial density of each species. The Jacobian will be computed numerically and I know how to do that in general.

Specifically though, are there any guidelines or requirements on how large (well, small really) the perturbations should be when evaluating the Jacobian numerically? Let's say the perturbation is defined relative to the size of the variable, so let's say the perturbation is X% of the variable. How should X be chosen? Should each variable have its own X or will a global one work? It should work in a mechanism-agnostic way, but I know most mechanisms will be very sensitive to temperature because it is in the exponential and less sensitive to changes in density or mass fraction since those are raised to exponents which are not excessively large.

I understand the idea behind the Jacobian and the Taylor Series expansions, so I'm looking more for practical advice in terms of accuracy, performance, and stability.

Comment: Are you using a library or writing something that doesn't have an adaptive step size for solving the system iteratively?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Well, this is for the source terms in a flow solver, so the time step adapts to the flow (and I suppose I could make it adapt to the chemistry as well), but the intention at this phase is that the chemistry does not affect the time step directly. Indirectly, it will alter the state and velocities and change the time step.

Comment: @tgp2114 - It sounds a little outside my area of knowledge (which is, at best, dated anyway in re: state of the art in numerical solvers). I suppose there's always some trial and error for determining the magnitude of perturbation you can get away with, although I hope some other user(s) on chem.SE can help you out here

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I think trial and error may be what I end up with anyway, I was just hoping for some guidance/bounds from best practices. I found an example source code online that set it to 1e-8 but had a comment that said "Note, this could be determined much better." I'm hoping somebody knows the much better specific to chemistry :)

Comment: This question would probably better be posted on [Computational Science.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). There's much greater expertise there with regard to this sort of algorithmic question.

Comment: @Brian I thought that also and am familiar with that community. I was hoping to get something more targeted for *chemistry* though since I have a feeling a chemistry solver might want to be treated differently than a general ODE solver. If it doesn't get any interest here, I'll ask for a migration.

Comment: @tpg2114 There is nothing typical about chemistry here. In the end everything is numbers. If you are just interested in finding solutions to your equations (and not design a new algorithm) then matlab has a good collection of stiff solvers. There are some freely available FORTRAN codes as well (ODEPACK). Finally, you can use some approximations in your mathematical model to convert it into a non-stiff system.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better asked at [Computational Science.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).